# Etymology of 必ず

Tags: etymology

In a comment on the question [Origin of あしからず](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/8294/origin-of-%E3%81%82%E3%81%97%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E3%81%9A#comment19561_8295), I wrote:

> What about 必ず? It's from 仮 + ならず. Does that fit the 形容動詞 + ならず pattern?

I said this because [大辞泉's entry for 必ず](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?p=%E5%BF%85%E3%81%9A&stype=0&dtype=0) says the following:

> ［副］《「かり（仮）ならず」の音変化》

However, [Dono responded by saying](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/8294/origin-of-%E3%81%82%E3%81%97%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E3%81%9A#comment19562_8295):

> That is one suggested etymology, but there is no general consensus.

If there is no consensus, are there other explanations for the etymology of 必ず?

Comment: It's interesting that the fake etymology/memory device I give myself to remember this Kanji is "cross my heart and hope to die" but I wonder how much of that phrase goes back to a common etymology for the two i.e. does a similar saying exist in Chinese?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, 大辞泉 is known to have a number of issues. You should get a second opinion on much of what it says. I'm away from most of my resources for the weekend, but below are quotes from several more reliable dictionaries at hand.

大辞林: 〔補説〕 「仮(かり)ならず」からできた語か

時代別国語大辞典：上代編：
ズは、おそらく否定の助動詞、カナラは活用語の未然形であろう。名義抄に「必（カナラジ）」とあるのも参考になる。そのカナラに関して、（イ）仮（かり）ナリの略、（ロ）兼ぬから派生した自動詞カナルを想定する、という説がある。（イ）は、仮でなく---ほんとうに、という意味変化の経路を（ロ）は、兼ねられてしまわずに---それだけが一すじに、というところからと考えるのであるが、いずれも決定的な根拠はない。

角川古語大辞典: 活用語の未然形に打消の「ず」の付いた形と考えられ、「必カナラジ（名義抄）」もこの推定を支える。「仮ならず」の転とする説、「彼ならず」の意とする説、「兼ぬ」から派生した動詞「かなる」を推定して、二道かけず一筋に、の意とする説などがある。

I am not strongly opposed, per se, to kari + narazu. A good argument may convince me. However, the evidence is lacking. Why does the medial -ri- disappear completely? Also, semantically, the relevance of 仮 to 必ず is questionable. Anyway, people have argued various etymologies over the years, but as above 「いずれも決定的な根拠はない」.

Comment: Somehow I'd gotten it into my head that this was か (question marker) + 成らず, i.e. "not in question" > "absolutely, certainly, no doubt".  Shogakukan also gives this 「かり（仮）ならず」の変化 etymology, but I too am not convinced.